# Правила обхода страниц Scrapy 1.2

Tags: python, парсер, python-2.x, scrapy

Доброго времени суток!
Необходимо написать паука на Python 2.7 с использованием фреймворка Scrapy для парса кинотеатров.
Начальная страница парса: http://kino-kassa.ru/vse-kinoteatry-rossii/

Паук должен переходить по каждой ссылке на город, и, из следующей страницы парсить название кинотеатра, его адресс, количество мест и количество кинозалов. Паук должен распарсить каждый город.

Как парсить данные с помощью XPath со страницы на которую он переходит я разобрался.

А вот как работать с правилами перехода паука по страницам и использование маршрутов (Rules) так и не понял.

Выкладываю код паука:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, Identity
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector
from crawl.items import cinemaItem


class cinemaLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = Identity()

class cinemaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "abiturlist"
    allowed_domains = ["kino-kassa.ru"]
    start_urls = ["http://kino-kassa.ru/vse-kinoteatry-rossii/"]


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('kinoteatry-*')), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        # all = hxs.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/div[3]/h2/a/text()")
        # all = hxs.xpath(".//*[@class='post']")
        all_name_cinema = hxs.xpath("//span[text()='Адрес кинотеатра: ']/../../..//div[@class='post-title']/*/a/text()").extract()
        all_address_cinema = hxs.xpath("//span[text()='Адрес кинотеатра: ']/../text()[1]").extract()
        all_count_of_seats_cinema = hxs.xpath("//span[text()='Количество залов: ']/../text()[9]").extract()
        all_count_of_halls_cinema = hxs.xpath("//span[text()='Количество залов: ']/../text()[7]").extract()
        # for fld in all:
        #     Item = cinemaItem()
        #     FIO = fld.xpath("./td[2]/p/text()").extract()[0].split()
        #     Item['family'] = FIO[0]
        #     Item['name'] = FIO[1]
        #     Item['surname'] = FIO[2]
        #     Item['spec'] = fld.xpath("./td[last()]/p/text()").extract()[0]
        #     ball = fld.xpath("string(./td[3]/p)").extract()[0]
        #     Item['ball'] = ball
        #     Item['url'] = response.url
        #     Item['pagespec'] = pg_spec
        #     yield Item
        i = 0
        while i < len(all_name_cinema):
            Item = cinemaItem()
            Item['name'] = all_name_cinema[i].split()
            Item['address'] = all_address_cinema[i].split()
            Item['count_of_seats'] = all_count_of_seats_cinema[i].split()
            Item['count_of_halls'] = all_count_of_halls_cinema[i].split()
            yield Item
            i += 1
```

Прошу прощение за корявость формата выложенного кода, но я еще не научился толком выкладывать код на Stack.
Заранее спасибо, надеюсь, что Вы мне поможете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('kino-kassa.ru/category/kinoteatr*')), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

Обеспечивает "нормальное" бегание по ссылкам которые находятся на странице `start_urls = ["http://kino-kassa.ru/vse-kinoteatry-rossii/"]` без обхода вложенные и "ненужных" ссылок